# Input pattern - Mobile number - Start with a specific numbers

Tags: html, forms

I trying to configure the pattern to be able to submit a mobile number that should start with **09** followed by a '0-9' digits. Total max characters are 11.

Sample: **09**493432199 or **09**267778595

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" pattern="[09]+[0-9]" maxlength="11"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this **RegExp**

It will match

- when the number starts with **09** **AND**
- when the number has exactly **11 digits**

  `pattern = /09[0-9]{9}/`

Try it out here
https://regex101.com/r/Nl2c2y/3

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" pattern="09[0-9]{9}" maxlength="11"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html seems nice

```
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" pattern="[0-9]" maxlength="11"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

You need also have JS like follow :

```
var username_prefix = $('#username').subsubstr(0,2);
$('#validate').click(function(){
if (username_prefix == 09) {
alert('correct');
}
else {
    alert('incorrect');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an expression with fixed digits plus a specific amount of digits.

If you need the exact 11 characters, then use `09[0-9]{9}`

In this example  `09[0-9]{8,9}` are valid 0912345678 and 09123456789

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" pattern="09[0-9]{8,9}" maxlength="11"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

As a side note, even if using `input pattern` is supported by the most common browsers, you should not rely only on the client side validation. Use a similar validation from the PHP backend to verify the information (in this case additional `^` (start of expression) and `$` (end of expression) were added.

```
if (!preg_match("/^09[0-9]{9}$/",$_GET["username"])){
  // not valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" pattern="[0-9]" title="Zero is required" maxlength="11"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```